# EF5 - removing related enities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF5 POCO entities (database first not code first, if that makes a difference). Say I have the following (hypothetical) entity types:-

- Store
- Customer (with a FK of StoreId)
- Product (with a FK of StoreId)
- Order (with FKs of CustomerId & ProductId)

A Store has many Customers and Products, and an Order is basically a M-M join between Customer and Product.

A typical scenario of mine involves retrieving a Store entity plus all of its related Customers, Products and Orders. With this hierarchy now in memory the user may choose to delete a Customer via the UI. As part of this action, I also want the Customer's related Orders to be deleted.

Is it sufficient to do:-

```
store.Customers.Remove(customerToDelete);
```

Or is it also necessary to "break the link" between the customer's Orders and their Products, e.g.:-

```
foreach (var order in customerToDelete.Orders)
{
    order.Product.Orders.Remove(order);
}
```

Note that the changes won't necessarily be persisted back to the DB straight away. The user may continue to work with this in-memory Store hierarchy, and only persist the changes upon clicking a "Save" button later. Therefore, if they continue to "browse" this hierarchy of entities via the UI, and drill down into a particular product, I don't want them to see orders relating to the removed customer. Hence I suspect I have to do the above `foreach` to wipe all trace of that customer's orders?

Not sure if it's related to my question, but can someone explain what the "End1 OnDelete" EDMX properties do? I understand how cascade deletes work in SQL, but not sure where this EDMX cascade option fits in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context will not automatically remove the orders owned by the Customer entity. Generally you will have a read only context for search results shown in your UI:

```
DbSet.Where(x => x == y).AsNoTracking()
```

So there will be no automatic refresh when you delete a customer from your data source as you will be using a fresh context for updates. This pattern is generally accepted now as you won't want to deal with the inevitable exceptions caused by updating your data source from a context containing stale entities. It's best to create a fresh context for a unit of work/scoped set of operations.

You can however set up a cascade delete using the [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#CascadeDelete)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Department)
    .WithMany(t => t.Courses)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartmentID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

This will do the job of removing the orders from the data source, but your orders visible through the UI will need to be refreshed/removed somehow. If your orders data is quite large then consider lazy loading, as you can [defer loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) your related entities until they are actually accessed which is great so long as you know what you are doing and don't accidently round trip when iterating through collections for example. Your approach of removing the entities manually after a delete is also fine, however, don't forget to delete the relationship/link separately, as this will hang around and possibly cause an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the "Store" example to keep my question simple, but in my real app the entity hierarchy is very self-contained, so stale data isn't an issue. I retrieve the entire hierarchy and pass it to the UI for the user to manipulate, and all these pending changes get persisted when they hit Save. I therefore need to be able to remove/delete entities in this "in memory" graph in such a way that a) the removed entities can no longer be seen by the user, and b) such changes will persist nicely back to the db when saved.